# Redefine implicit identifiers in Standard ML

Tags: scope, sml

I would like to define function `div`, but get an exception kind of

```
Error: expression or pattern ends with infix identifier "div"
```

As far as I understand `div` is not a keyword, but regular function. Or am I wrong? If so there should be possible redefine this function. Can I remove identifiers from the scope? Is there something like NoImplicitPrelude in Haskell?

### update

The question then took this form: how to remove the infix status?

Answer (score 2):

To use an infix identifier as nonfix, you have to put the keyword `op` in front. For example:

```
val op + = 0
val op div = op *
fun op + (x, y) = op @ (y, x)
fun op div (x, y) = x * y
```

The `fun` syntax also allows using infix operators for definitions as is:

```
fun x / y = x * y
```

Fwiw, you can also define your own infix operators:

```
infix ++
fun x ++ y = (x + y) - 1

infix times
fun x times y = x * y
```

Edit: You can also remove infix status by declaring it `nonfix`:

```
nonfix div
fun div x = 1/x
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to make it binary operator. I want interpret `div` as an html element.

Comment: Oh, for that you can use a nonfix declaration, see my edit. Though I wouldn't recommend changing the meaning of predefined operators like that, since it would not play nicely with other libraries.

Comment: Even with limited scope? SML has lexical scoping, so this shouldn't break other libraries, wouldn't it?

Comment: It wouldn't per se, but wouldn't you want to turn something HTML-related into a module? And then client code likely would want to `open` that module.

Comment: Yes, I would to make it as a module. As far as I understand, client code has to remove infix status from `div` explicitly, even though I use `nonfix div` inside my module. I don't understand, what kind of negative consequences of redefining "standard" operators (or their fixity) can occur.

Comment: Except for the fact that you have to `nonfix div` every time you `open` your HTML tag module, and syntax highlighters may assume that `div` is something other than a tag and apply a little too much color, I don't think you'll have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320656/1722399)

```
type elem = {tag:string, attrs: (string*string) list}
nonfix div
fun div attrs : elem = {tag = "div", attrs = attrs}
```